# Le but du composant est permettre l'accès aux résultats

Tags: grammaire

Dans la phrase en titre je me demande s'il ne serait pas plus correct d'utiliser la forme suivante :

> *Le but du composant est ***de*** permettre l'accès aux résultats*

Donc, de rajouter la préposition *de*.

Quelle est la meilleure formulation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***De*** ne sert que d'introducteur à l'infinitif, un peu comme le ***to*** anglais. On ne le retrouve pas si l'on inverse la phrase, ce qui ne change en rien son sens :

> Permettre l'accès aux résultats est le but du composant.

On peut aussi remplacer ce ***de*** par une pause :

> Le but du composant est : permettre l'accès aux résultats.

Answer (score 4):

Le "de" est ici requis, en effet.

Comment: Bonjour @user25476 et bienvenue sur FSE. Afin de rendre cette réponse (exacte) plus pertinente, il serait bien de l'étayer un peu, par exemple en incluant une source vers la règle de grammaire qui explique le fait que le "de" soit requis ici.

Comment: +1 Pouvez-vous l'expliquer pourquoi ?

Answer (score 0):

Ici l'infinitif "permettre" a une fonction d'attribut du sujet. Pour remplir cette fonction, il doit être précédé de la préposition "de".

La règle me semble un peu floue cependant. Prenons par exemple : "Partir c'est mourir un peu." Ici pas de préposition, l'infinitif est une référence au mot "mourir" davantage qu'à l'action qu'il signifie.

Sans être expert de la grammaire, je rapproche l'usage de la préposition "de" avec l'infinitif de celui qu'on en a avec les inqualifiables ("de l'eau", "de l'essence").